# How to list audio files from Media Player and then play them in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-music-player

I want to get the list of all the songs that are added in the media player in android. 
if i dont have a path to where all the music files are stored,then how can i retrieve the list of the songs?

is there any way to get the path where the songs are stored without taking the path from the user?

UPDATED->> i got the list. now i want to play the selected song from another activity when i am just passing the song name. is that possible? and how??

Please help. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code to get mp3 from SDCard :-

```
final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .getPath() + "/";
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
private String mp3Pattern = ".mp3";

// Constructor
public SongsManager() {

}

/**
 * Function to read all mp3 files and store the details in
 * ArrayList
 * */
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList() {
    System.out.println(MEDIA_PATH);
    if (MEDIA_PATH != null) {
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
        File[] listFiles = home.listFiles();
        if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
            for (File file : listFiles) {
                System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    scanDirectory(file);
                } else {
                    addSongToList(file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // return songs list array
    return songsList;
}

private void scanDirectory(File directory) {
    if (directory != null) {
        File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();
        if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
            for (File file : listFiles) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    scanDirectory(file);
                } else {
                    addSongToList(file);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

private void addSongToList(File song) {
    if (song.getName().endsWith(mp3Pattern)) {
        HashMap<String, String> songMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        songMap.put("songTitle",
                song.getName().substring(0, (song.getName().length() - 4)));
        songMap.put("songPath", song.getPath());

        // Adding each song to SongList
        songsList.add(songMap);
    }
}
```

or

```
final Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    final String[] cursor_cols = {
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
    };
    final String where = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "=1";
    final Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, cursor_cols, where, null, null);
    cursor.moveToNext();
    final String artist = cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
    final String album = cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
    final String track = cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
    doSomethingHere(artist, album, track);
```